# TabNavigator re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tabnavigator

I use TabNavigator in react-native and i would like re-render when I navigate but I can not do it ... Someone know how do that ??

My try :
navigation.js

```
const Navigation = TabNavigator({
    Listing: {screen: ListingScreen},
    Preferences: {screen: PreferencesScreen},
    Add: {screen: AddScreen},
    Calendar: {screen: CalendarScreen},
    Professional: {screen: ProfessionalScreen},
}, 
{
    initialRouteName: 'Add',
    tabBarOptions: {
        activeTintColor: 'blue',
        activeBackgroundColor: 'grey',
        inactiveTintColor: 'black',
    },
});

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Navigation
          screenProps={{ prop: "I am a Props !" }}
        />
      );
    }
  }
```

Page navigation 
professional.js

```
export default class Professional extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Professional',
        tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {jumpToIndex(scene.index), console.log("Professional")},
    };
   render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={{marginTop: '80%', marginLeft: '40%'}}> Professional </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to re-render every time user changed tabs or just for the initial change? `lazy` prop waits for tab to be changed to render. Maybe this can help.

Comment: Yes i want re-render every time, lazy render once when user select the page but not re-render after ;) but think for read

Comment: Can you give a little bit more context on why do you want to re-render and whats gonna change after you re-render. For example is it to re-render a flatlist because of a data change etc.

Comment: It's that on 1 page I display list of objects and on other page I create a new object but when I create it i would like update first page for see the new object